# What does $g^1$ represent in group theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was going through the definition of "order of an element" and in the examples following it the author had considered the group $U(15)$ under multiplication modulo $15$, where it was calculating the order of each element there it was given,
$7^1 = 7$, $7^2 = 4 $...
Now I understand that $7^1 = 7\pmod{15} = 7$. But In group theory where we talk about binary operations what does $g^1$ even mean? Don't we need two elements to perform Binary operation.

Comment: If $g$ belongs to a group $G$, $g^1=g$.

Comment: But then $g^2$ represents $g*g$ where $g \in G$ so why represent it as $g^1$ plus it writes $7^1$ = following it up with $7^2$ = 4 wouldn't it imply that $7^1  = 7mod15 = 7$

Comment: If $G$ is a group written multiplicatively with identity $e$, for any $g\in G$ we define recursively $g^0=e$, $g^{n+1}=g^ng$, and for $n\gt 0$, $g^{-n}=(g^n)^{-1}$. It's notation. If $G$ is written additively with identity $0$, then we define $0g=0$, $(n+1)g=ng+g$, and $(-n)g=-(ng)$. Again, this is just notation.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here. This is a good question - the notation $g^1$ is ubiquitous in group theory, yet as the question points out it makes no sense.

Comment: @user1729 I didn't downvote, but saying "it makes no sense" is rather an overstatement. If you have a multiplicative structure, there is an obvious meaning to something like "$g^2$", "$g^3$"; and we make "$g^{-1}$" have a meaning that is completely consistent with that, so there is no obstacle to extending this in an obvious manner to $g^1$, just like we do in basic algebra and calculus. There's nothing wrong with being confused, but to assert that the notation "makes no sense" is taking it too far.

Comment: @Arturo Sure, but the phrasing "makes no sense" is mine and shouldn't be held against the question :-) I agree that there *is* an obvious definition, but it is not necessarily clear that the meaning of $g^1$ meshes with the obvious thing. I think students thinking critically about this sort of thing and questioning what they read is good, but in contrast there is a temptation of more mathematically mature people to think these kinds of questions are obvious so shouldn't be asked. But being obvious to them doesn't mean it it obvious to others.

Comment: (or to put it another way: I would expect a good book or set of notes to explicitly define what $g^1$ means. The fact that it is defined means that someone who has seen the notation without the definition can and should questions what is means - because without the definition they can only guess.)

Comment: @user1729 As I said, I didn't downvote. There is plenty pf notation that is not very intelligible without a definition (e.g., the similar-looking notation $A^B$ for *sets*). Here, we are already using exponents like $-1$, And there is already an understanding of what $x^2$, $x^3$, etc. mean. I think you are not apprehending the nature of the confusion here. I think it is that if multiplication requires two factors, how do we multiply just one thing? But again, OP is fine with that in modular arithmetic, making the confusion harder to justify.

Comment: @user1729 I would liken it to the common confusion of defining an empty product or sum (which amounts to a convenient definition), but "one step removed" as it were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally if $G$ is a group with the neutral element $e\in G$, $g\in G$ is any element and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is an integer then $g^n$ is defined by the following rules:

$$g^0:=e$$
$$g^n:=gg^{n-1}\text{ for }n>0$$
$$g^n:=(g^{-1})^{-n}\text{ when }n<0$$

The middle rule is recursive. In the last one note that when $n<0$ then $-n>0$ and so $(g^{-1})^{-n}$ is well defined by the previous rule.

Few examples that follow from this definition:

$$g^1=gg^0=ge=g$$
$$g^2=gg^1=gg$$
$$g^3=gg^2=ggg$$
$$g^{-2}=(g^{-1})^2=g^{-1}g^{-1}$$
$$g^{-3}=(g^{-1})^3=g^{-1}g^{-1}g^{-1}$$

and so on.

Comment: $g^1$ is not a binary operation and by definition in group theory there is an binary operation on the elements of the same set.

Comment: $g^1$ is *defined* using the binary operation $\cdot$ of the group as $g^1 = g\cdot g^0 = g\cdot e$.

Comment: @user1729 I suppose the discussion about "binary operation" term indeed is irrelevant. I've removed that part.

Comment: OK, great, I've removed my comment and added a +1 :-)